# PHP - Remove multiple lines from a file using a exception file

Tags: php, html, file

I have a text file which contains:

```
text1 bla bla
text2 bla2 bla2
text3 bla3 bla4
text4 bla4 bla7
text5 bla8 bla7
text6 bla9 blu1
```

and another file which contains:

```
bla7
bla3
text1
```

I want to create a PHP script that creates a new file based off the first one, only including lines which don't contain text from the second file. Using the examples above, I would expect to have the following result:

```
text2 bla2 bla2
text6 bla9 blu1
```

I read other posts and I tried to use the code below, but it only removes a single word.

```
$lines  = file('test.txt');
$search = 'text2';

$result = '';
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(stripos($line, $search) === false) {
        $result .= $line;
    }
}
file_put_contents('cleanfile.txt', $result);
```

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong and how to make the code work for multiple words would be appreciated.

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question, or a problem statement. We will help you fix bugs or answer specific questions about your code, not just do your work for you completely. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question. Thanks. (P.S. Consider creating an array of words and looping through them, searching for each one in turn within every line...)

Comment: Read in the second file and loop it inside the existing loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you join the exclusion words with OR `|`, then you can grep for lines with those words and exclude them:

```
$result = preg_grep('/\b' . implode('|', file('exclusions.txt')) . '\b/i',
                    file('test.txt'),
                    PREG_GREP_INVERT);

file_put_contents('cleanfile.txt', $result);
```

The `\b` makes sure that there is a word boundary so that `bla` doesn't match `bla2` for example.  The `i` modifier makes it case-insensitive since you used `stripos`.